# AWS Cognito Password Regex - Specific to AWS Cognito

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, oauth, passwords, amazon-cognito

Can someone give me the regex to match a valid AWS Cognito password - with numbers, special characters (their list), lower and upper case letters

The AWS Cognito default length limit is 6 characters and has it's own list of special characters

### Note that the AWS Congito password regex is specific to AWS Congnito - not just a general password regex.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Updated Answer - March 2023

---

```
/^(?!\s+)(?!.*\s+$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$^*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+\- ])[A-Za-z0-9$^*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+\- ]{8,256}$/
```

### Explanation

- `/` Indicates the start of a regular expression.
- `^` Beginning. Matches the beginning of the string.
- `(?!\s+)` Disallows leading spaces.
- `(?!.*\s+$)` Disallows trailing spaces.
- `(?=.*[a-z])` Requires lowercase letters.
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` Requires uppercase letters.
- `(?=.*[0-9])` Requires numbers.
- `` (?=.*[\^$*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+\- ]) `` Requires at least one special character from the specified set. (The non-leading, non-trailing space character is also treated as a special character.)
- `` [A-Za-z0-9^$*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+\- ]{8,256} `` Minimum 8 characters from the allowed set, maximum 256 characters.
- `$` End. Matches the end of the string.
- `/` Indicates the end of a regular expression.

The minimum character limit defaults to 8 but can be customised to a value between 6 and 99. The full length of a password however is limited to 256 characters (not 99).

### Interactive Example

https://regexr.com/79p07

### Documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html

#### Inaccuracies in documentation

Cognito also has a "no leading or trailing spaces" rule in the default password requirements, but there are several docs out there that incorrectly state that "The space character is also treated as a special character". However, the current behaviour is actually "The non-leading, non-trailing space character is also treated as a special character".

To see the correct default password rules, view a user pool, click on the "Sign-in experience" tab, and click on "Contains at least 1 special character" to bring up a tooltip with the rules.

Comment: The above regex failed for me as it was missing some special characters. I've updated it here to work with the default cognito password config: 
`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[=+\-^$*.\[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~\`])\S{8,99}$/`

Comment: According to https://regex101.com/ the regex is invalid because a forward slash is not escaped. PLUS we had real problems using this regex in the deployed react version on an S3 bucket (locally it worked). Also I question that 6 chars is the default I think it's 8.

Comment: @CodingYourLife sorry this  gave you trouble - what was the issue? I see on regex101.com it complains when used in PHP - if you used it in React it should have been valid. Both PHP and JS seem happy with the forward slash escaped so I will update the answer. I also see 8 is now the default - again I will update.

Comment: +1 for @CodingYourLife 's comment about not working on S3.  We faced the same issue...works perfectly in local environment but not when deployed to S3.  Seems like odd behavior.  Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: I had a similar problem with this regex where it worked locally but not in production (React SPA on AWS). I carefully retyped the regex letter by letter and it was fixed, so I think the problem was coming from exotic quotations when I had originally copy/pasted. Try this:
```/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\^$*.\[\]{}\(\)?\-"!@#%&\/,><\':;|_~`])\S{8,99}$/```

Comment: @hugo here is it deployed to S3 where it seems to work fine. http://awspasswordregex.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ code is simple so view source if you want to see how it works. I will update the answer to use the regular quotations - thanks indigoi

Comment: Cognito defaults include =, - and +. Unfortunately they're not listed in the official documentation, but by default they are admitted by Cognito. These are taken straight from the Cognito AWS Console:

`(^ $ * . [ ] { } ( ) ? - " ! @ # % & / \ , > < ' : ; | _ ~ `` + =)`

Comment: Would be useful to add references to this answer to understand where it's come from/what specifications it's based on.

Comment: @JonathanIrwin, I think using `\S` is a rather large mistake in your regexp.  Now this may have been a little different when you put the regexp together, however according to AWS today a password is allowed to contain upper & lower case basic latin letters, numbers, and special characters from the list.  It must also contain fewer than 99 characters so you need to reduce the max length by 1.  `\S` will allow anything that isn't whitespace, so as long as the password satisfies the "contains a *" lookaheads it can contain any other characters that aren't in the allowed set.  Continued...

Comment: I propose tightly defining the allowed character set of your regexp with:
`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\^$*.\[\]{}\(\)?\"!@#%&\/\\,><\':;|_~\`=+\-])[a-zA-Z0-9\^$*.\[\]{}\(\)?\"!@#%&\/\\,><\':;|_~\`=+\-]{8,98}$/`
The current Cognito password requirements specifications are available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html.

(I'd add this answer myself but some bright spark closed this question because it looked similar to another one)

Comment: Regarding regex for special characters, see below an up to date one :

```/[\^$*.\[\]{}\(\)?"!@#%&\\\/,><\':;|_~`=+\- ]/;```

Comment: The 99 character limit is actually the cap on minimum password length.
A Cognito password can be up to 256 characters in length. The minimum can be between 6 and 99 as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html).

Also, contrary to the comments above, "The space character is also treated as a special character.".

Comment: @jfgilmore I see what you mean about the length. I will update the answer

Comment: Thank you @jfgilmore, you've caught a few bits that I missed from the spec so I'll update what I'm using accordingly.

Comment: @Andrew's Regex works better

Comment: The regex does not work if the password contains the char §

Comment: @Charles any idea how to fix it? Does cognito accept that as a valid special character?

Comment: Yes Cognito allows that char. I would suggest adding `(.)` at the end of the regex: 
```/^(?!\s+)(?!.*\s+$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$^*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+\- ])[A-Za-z0-9$^*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+\- ](.){8,256}$/```

Answer (score 1):

the Regex formula for Swift 5 is

```
"(.*[()!@^$*.?\\-@#%&\":;|><'_~`+=\\[\\],{}])"
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the default requirements based on the AWS console settings and the current [Cognito documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html):

- No leading or trailing spaces
- At least one uppercase basic Latin letter
- At least one lowercase basic Latin letter
- At least one Arabic numeral <sup>1</sup>
- At least one of:
  ^ $ * . [ ] { } ( ) ? " ! @ # % & / \ , > < ' : ; | _ ~ ` = + -
- 8-256 characters
- Other than leading and trailing spaces, any characters are allowed, including spaces and emojis <sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> The restriction to Arabic numerals is not specified in the documentation, but I experimented and found that other Unicode digits do not count toward this requirement

<sup>2</sup> The accepted answer limits the allowed characters to the characters that are *required*, however more characters are allowed than are required. The [Cognito documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html) says, "After Amazon Cognito verifies that passwords contain the minimum required characters, your users' passwords can contain *additional characters of any type* up to the maximum password length." Cognito is perfectly happy with the following password, for instance: `Ab!~1 ℉”•—”†„简体字`.

This regex handles all of the above scenarios:

```
/^(?!\s+)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\^$*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+-]).{8,256}(?<!\s)$/
```

Explanation:

- `^(?!\s+)` No leading spaces
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` At least one uppercase letter
- `(?=.*[a-z])` At least one lowercase letter
- `(?=.*[0-9])` At least one digit
- `` (?=.*[\^$*.[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`=+-]) `` At least one of: ^ $ * . [ ] { } ( ) ? " ! @ # % & / \ , > < ' : ; | _ ~ ` = + - (listed in the same order as in the [Cognito documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html))
- `.` Other than leading and trailing spaces, any characters are allowed,
  including spaces and emojis
- `{8,256}` 8-256 characters
- `(?<!\s)$` No trailing spaces